# Select created/modified date of a stored procedure

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Is there a way in Firebird to select a created and modified date for a stored procedure? I know it can be done in SQL Server, but I'm working with Firebird 2.5.

Comment: Most probably there is no - https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx04-procedures.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be done with Firebird alone. As [this page state](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx04-procedures.html) there are no dates of creation, modification. However it could be done in IBExpert as [Version History](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.View#VersionHistory).